# WPF Rotate and return BitmapSource by any angle

Tags: wpf, rotation, bitmapsource

Hei, I tried this:

```
public static BitmapSource RotateImage(Image b, float angle)
    {
        BitmapSource rotita = (BitmapSource)b.Source;

        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

        using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            var transform = new RotateTransform(angle);
            drawingContext.PushTransform(transform);
            drawingContext.DrawImage(rotita, new Rect(0,0, rotita.PixelWidth, rotita.PixelHeight));
            drawingContext.Pop();
        }

        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(rotita.PixelWidth, rotita.PixelHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(drawingVisual);

        rotita = bmp;

        return rotita;
    }
```

But this does not work fine. I have this [image at 0 degree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnyKh.png) and after rotation at 30 degrees [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTlxi.png).

What could I make the picture to be complete after rotation?

```
DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();            

        using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            drawingContext.DrawImage(back, new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));            
            drawingContext.DrawImage(element, new Rect(x,y, elementWidth, elementHeight));
        }

        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(drawingVisual);


        image.Source = bmp;
```

Element is the rotated image

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't simply apply the transform to the RenderTransform or LayoutTransform property of the Image element that shows the bitmap? It is unclear what you mean with "*the picture to be complete after rotation*". The resulting RenderTargetBitmap is still an axis-aligned rectangular pixel raster. And when you rotate a rectangle inside an enclosing axis-aligned rectangle, it should be clear that the outer rectangle is larger than the inner, rotated one.

Comment: because I want the image to be drawn over another image:

Comment: Please edit your question. Do not post code in comments.

Comment: Why can't you put two Image elements on top of each other? Note that using DrawingVisuals isn't very common. It's not how WPF is typically used.

Comment: Shortly, I want to overlay a rotated image over another that is not rotated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method creates a composed bitmap from two others, where the second one is rotated around their common center point.

The two crucial parts of this method are the calculation of the transformed bounds of the rotated bitmap, and the alignment of the two bitmaps at their common center point.

```
private BitmapSource ComposeImage(
    BitmapSource image1, BitmapSource image2, double rotationAngle)
{
    var rotation = new RotateTransform(rotationAngle);
    var size1 = new Size(image1.PixelWidth, image1.PixelHeight);
    var size2 = new Size(image2.PixelWidth, image2.PixelHeight);
    var center1 = new Vector(size1.Width / 2, size1.Height / 2);
    var center2 = new Vector(size2.Width / 2, size2.Height / 2);
    var rotatedSize = rotation.TransformBounds(new Rect(size2)).Size;
    var totalSize = new Size(
        Math.Max(size1.Width, rotatedSize.Width),
        Math.Max(size1.Height, rotatedSize.Height));
    var center = new Point(totalSize.Width / 2, totalSize.Height / 2);

    rotation.CenterX = center.X;
    rotation.CenterY = center.Y;

    var dv = new DrawingVisual();

    using (var dc = dv.RenderOpen())
    {
        dc.DrawImage(image1, new Rect(center - center1, size1));
        dc.PushTransform(rotation);
        dc.DrawImage(image2, new Rect(center - center2, size2));
    }

    var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)totalSize.Width, (int)totalSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    rtb.Render(dv);

    return rtb;
}
```